# How to use images for a JPanel grid?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I'm trying to create an 8x8 grid composed of pre made images to be used for a board game, however I am having difficulty loading the images.

```
    Dimension Size = new Dimension(400, 400);

    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize(Size);
    getContentPane().add(layeredPane);

    board.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
    board.setPreferredSize(Size);
    board.setBounds(0, 0, Size.width, Size.height);
    layeredPane.add(board, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    //  Load squares to board

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            JPanel square = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
            square. // Load .jpg here?????
            board.add( square );
        }
    }
```

The only method I know is ImageIcon, but that doesn't seem to work... So I'm stuck.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Hint: `JLabel` has an `Icon` property

Answer (score 3):

ImageIcon should work fine. See the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: These images are to be used as background images for other pieces(JLabels) to move around on, are Icons OK for this?

Comment: Strangely, yes.  The BG `ImageIcon` can be displayed in a `JLabel`, which can in turn have a layout set on it to accept other components added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet, adapted from [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm):

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
private Image img;

public ImagePanel(URL imgURL) {
    this(new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage());
}

public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}
}
```

You can add those ImagePanels inside the JPanel

Comment: Please, call `super.paintComponent(g)` otherwise you can potentially end up with nasty paint artifacts

Comment: 1) `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);`  A `JPanel` **is an** `ImageObserver` so that would better be `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);`. 2)  Always call `super.paintComponent(g);` first! 3) `this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());`  Since `img` is a `String` and is probably an [tag:embedded-resource] by run-time, the image must be accessed by `URL`. 4) `new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));`  Again, should be `new Dimension(img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this));`